# nodejs server running from service giving error "Failed to execute command: Exec format error"

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, services

I'm not very good at server admin work, forgive me if I'm missing any steps.

I have a node express server that runs just fine normally, I was deploying it with `forever` but now I would like to move it over to a system service. I created my service file in `/lib/systemd/system/myservice.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=website service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.0/bin/node /home/myuser/WSProject/src/server/index.js
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I got this config following a guide. I have confirmed that the node path is correct, and is the path that is returned when I use `which node`. I restart the daemon, and restart the service. The service fails. If I check the journalctl for the service, I can see the following error:

```
Jul 30 12:55:03 psjqw2q9h systemd[1]: Started Run the encore server.
Jul 30 12:55:03 psjqw2q9h systemd[22298]: myservice.service: Failed to execute command: Exec format error
Jul 30 12:55:03 psjqw2q9h systemd[22298]: myservice.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/myuser/WSProject/src/server/index.js: Exec format error
Jul 30 12:55:03 psjqw2q9h systemd[1]: myservice.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jul 30 12:55:03 psjqw2q9h systemd[1]: myservice.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 30 12:55:03 psjqw2q9h systemd[1]: myservice.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 30 12:55:03 psjqw2q9h systemd[1]: myservice.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Jul 30 12:55:03 psjqw2q9h systemd[1]: Stopped Run the encore server.
```

That's all I got. I don't know how to troubleshoot this further. There are similar issues to this I can find, but there either node nodejs related, or something trivial like a space in the config file. I tried various forms of wrapping the ExecStart command in quotes as one post describes. I had a user line in there at some point but it didn't make a difference weather I set it to the root user, or some other user, or leaving it out entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to adjust permissions on the myservice.service file, and then to add a WorkingDirectory value to the location the node application needed to be run from.